# Is there a way go start google search from Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: 13.04, search, google

I'm not talking about the Google Desktop Search, I'm looking for something more like an android-style widget, where I can enter the search term while on the desktop and it will launch the browser with the search results.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can install the Screenlets widgets and find one, I think I remember a google search widget.

Comment: I did not see any widget as you asked...

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been looking for, thanks.